# UpdatePanel is affecting controls outside of itself

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel, inline-code

I have a basic updatepanel on a webforms page.  Outside of the updatepanel on the page, I have a few <%= inline expressions %>.

When the updatepanel updates, it works.  But when I step through the code that executes on that ajax postback, after the updatepanel finishes loading its contents, I can see that it goes on to try and re-render other elements on the page.  Since I have not reassigned the properties that are accessed by the inline expression during the postback, the properties are null, and an exception gets thrown.

Two part question:
1) Why is the server executing code render blocks located outside of the update panel?
2) If an exception gets thrown while I'm stepping through the code, why can't I see it when I'm not stepping through the code (YSOD?)?

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel partial post backs run through the entire page lifecycle on the parent page.  You can't get the partial page runtime error (YSOD) because it is an AJAX call.  If you inspect the return with Firebug/Fiddler sometimes you can see a stack trace, otherwise you have to debug the really see what is happening.